# How to import prime component direct to *.vue file instead of importing it to main *.js file in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

my apiCall.vue file is as below and I wanted to add directly prime component here instead of loading it from index.js file. I wanted to remove component from js file and wanted to use directly into vue file. is it possible?

```
 <template>
<DataTable :value="cars">
    <Column field="vin" header="Vin"></Column>
    <Column field="year" header="Year"></Column>
</DataTable>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'ApiCall',
  data() {
        return {
            columns: null,
            cars: null
        }
  },
  mounted() {
         this.columns = [
            {field: 'vin', header: 'Vin'},
            {field: 'year', header: 'Year'},
            {field: 'brand', header: 'Brand'},
            {field: 'color', header: 'Color'}
        ];
        this.cars =[
        {vin:'dsad231ff',year:'2012',brand:'Volkswagen',color:'Orange'},
        {vin:'dsad231ff',year:'2012',brand:'Volkswagen',color:'Orange'},
        {vin:'dsad231ff',year:'2012',brand:'Volkswagen',color:'Orange'},
        {vin:'j6w54qgh',year:'2009',brand:'BMW',color:'Blue'}
        ];
     }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

and my index.js file is al below:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import DataTable from 'primevue/datatable';
import Column from 'primevue/column';

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.component('DataTable', DataTable);
Vue.component('Column', Column);

function lazyLoad(view){
  return() => import(`@/views/${view}.vue`)
}
const routes = [
  {
      path: '/apiCall',
      name: 'ApiCall',
      component: lazyLoad('ApiCall')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

I am new to Vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the components inside the .vue files script section:

```
<script>
import DataTable from 'primevue/datatable';
import Column from 'primevue/column';
export default {
...
  components: {
    DataTable,
    Column
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: hi, it is working in my first try, but it is not working when I used it with VueMaterial, any suggestion?

Comment: it is not possible with vue-material npm as per below link, so better not to use for enhancing performance. Use primevue instead.
https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/1166